# Python Switch to Current Opened Window in Firefox

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

Hi! I am trying to write a script which goes to url click and in the opening window take some data, but I cannot make it switch to the new opened window, this is the only function I could find with google, but doesn't seem to work. I use selenium 2.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());

find_element_by_name('sellorq').click()

get1 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@style="text-align:right;background-color:#efefef"]//tr/td[3]')

get2 = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@style="text-align:right;background-color:#efefef"]//tr/td[2]')
```

Comment: 'find_element_by_name('sellorq').click()' --- does this line open the new window? If this is the case, it would seem logical to put it before the line 'driver.SwitchTo().Window(driver.WindowHandles.Last());'

Comment: No it is different button, this part the new window has already opened.

Comment: Selenium tests run very fast. May be, it's taking time to open another window. Hence, use sleep before switching to window. THis might help. Also if you paste here the error, it will help to help you.

Comment: Yes I added time.sleep(2) and it's ok now. Thanks for advice